# Animation of ImageView cancel OntouchEvent why?

Tags: android, animation, touch-event

When i touch a Imageview i call an animation for anather imageview. the animation is successfully occur but it cancel the Ontouch event so that the UP Event in Ontouch is not called when i up my finger from the Imageview, How to make them such that the UP Event will also be call. i search for it allot but i can't find anything.
My code is below:` fingerPlaceImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                animationImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                handlerTimer.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 2500);
            }
            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                animationImageView.clearAnimation();

                if (handlerTimer!=null) {
                    handlerTimer.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Return the true make the Ontouch Event Live. hence when the return is true then the UP/DOWN is live and Event will Occure on UP/Down.